# Random numbers in quick succession

Tags: c#, random

I need to generate a sequence of random numbers in quick succession, however the structure of my application means that **I can't reuse the same `Random` object**.

So what I need to do is, in essence:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication5 {
  class Program {
    static void Main() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(new Random().Next(int.MaxValue));
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

However, this obviously returns repeats of the same generated number because the seed used is based on the system clock and the loop is being iterated so quickly.

Note that the number of random numbers to be generated is small (~100 or so), so it doesn't matter if the algorithm is poor. Note that obviously since I can't keep a reference to the `Random` object, I can't use the last generated value as the seed in the next call either since this is also not available.

How can I get a different number each time?

TIA

Comment: What's preventing you from keeping a reference to the generator?  Since you need such a small number, is there any reason not to pre-generate them?

Comment: That's a pretty strange restriction: the inability to create a persistent object. Care to elaborate on why that restriction exists?

Comment: Why can't you re-use the Random object? Can't you just toss it in a member variable or a static somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really can't create a persistent `Random` class instance, you could use the [RandomNumberGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class to get some random bytes, and then use those to calculate your random number. You'd have to create a new instance every time, of course, and that class is somewhat slower than `Random`, but it would do what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

Change to:

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(rand.Next(int.MaxValue));
```

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881853/how-random-is-system-random-rnd-new-system-random/5881894#5881894

Comment: As I said in the first line of the question, this is not possible.

Comment: @ena That's really weird restriction.. glad you found alternative though.

Answer (score 5):

Don't `new` a random each time.

```
  var random = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(random.Next(int.MaxValue));
```

Comment: As I said in the first line of the question, this is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a static variable:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication5 
{
    class Program 
    {
        private static readonly Random _random = new Random();

        static void Main() 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(_random.Next(int.MaxValue));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

or use a local Random variable which you would instantiate outside of the for loop and reuse inside.

Comment: As I said in the first line of the question, this is not possible.

Comment: @enashnash, well this case I am afraid you will have to write your own custom implementation of a pseudo random number generator which does this as the Random class has not been designed to be used the way you are using it.